# Reverse each word in a given string

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

Its is code to reverse word in string please help me i a m not getting output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
//an array
char arr[1000];
int top=-1;
void push(char tm){
if(top<1000){
    top++;
    arr[top]=tm;

}

}

void pop(){
while(top!=-1){
    printf("%c",arr[top]);
    top=top-1;
}
printf(".");
}
int main() {
//code
int noc=0;
char fin[10000];
int len;
scanf("%d",&noc);
for(int i=0;i<noc;i++){
scanf("%s",fin);
len=strlen(fin);
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){

    if(fin[i]=="."){ 
        pop();}
    else{
        push(fin[i]);


    }

  }
  printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
   }
```

Input:
2
i.like.this.program.very.much

pqr.mno

Output:
i.ekil.siht.margorp.yrev.hcum

rqp.onm

asdf
ad
a

aaaa
a
a
a
aa
a

aaaasdasdasdasd
as
d
asd
as
d
as
dasd

Comment: If `fin[i] == '.'` you need to pop the entire stack; not just one element.  Also, you are comparing character (`fin[i]`) with a string (`"."`).  You need to fix that.

Comment: i wrote pop so that it will empty the stack and how can i compare without using == operator?

Comment: `fin[i]` is character, compare it with character not with string `""`. This `fin[i]=="."`--> `fin[i]=='.'`

Comment: even though i am not getting right answer can anyone correct this

Comment: After `mno` there is no `.` so how will you solve this ?

Comment: its the 2nd test case